# search for a file with PYTHON without path

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following python-script, which open a text-file:

```
import sys
file = r"D:/...../text.txt"
with open (file,"r") as infile:
text = infile.read()

print (text)
```

If I want to run this script on another computer, i have to change the path (the same text-file "text.txt" will be saved on the other computer). Is there any way to let my script search the computer for the text-file without writing the path in the script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in a relative directory, e.g.:

```
import sys
file = r"text.txt"
with open (file,"r") as infile:
  text = infile.read()

print (text)
```

Just keeping the text file in the same directory as the small program.

Comment: I dont have access to the other computer. The directory of the text-file on the other computer is unknown. Whitouht changing anything in my script and without searching for the directory on the other computer, the script should be able to find the text-file and read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) to get the result you want, but the glob will return a list of files, you may need to adapt your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using a GUI for "choose file"

```
import sys 
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

master = Tk()
master.withdraw() #hiding tkinter window

file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title="Open file", filetypes=[("txt file",".txt"),("All files",".*")])

with open (file_path,"r") as infile:
    text = infile.read()

print (text)
```

Comment: ImportError: No module named Tkinter. what could be the solution?

Comment: Install TKinter: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html (included with all standard Python distributions since 3.1) and then use py2exe

Comment: I did install TKinter, but still have the same problem!!

Comment: @user1071404 use "import tkinter"